# Can I iterate through for loop to create more javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have multiple `.click()` functions populated on page load, based on how many image records are stored within a mysql database.

so far i have a page that will nicely switch between photos with a `<ul>` of image buttons

but i have to hand write the jquery that deals with it.

is there a way that i can populate a `.js` file with the correct amount of `.click()` functions based on the amount of records on in the data base.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Alex's answer, if you want to set the click event of elements that don't exist yet or haven't been added to the page, you could do:

```
$(body).on('click','a.record',function(){
    //any existing or future a element with class record will have this click function
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a separate `onclick` handler to each element, you should use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and attach a single event handler to some container. Said event handles would catch all the `onclick` events , as the bubble up through DOM.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to write a `click()` for each unique element.

Instead, you could *select* a bunch of elements with a selector, such as `$('a.record')` and then chain `click()` to that...

```
$('a.record').click(function() {
   // Any `a` element with a class of `record` was clicked.
});
```

The disadvantage of doing it this way is you add a bunch of event listeners and it won't be triggered for future elements.

As others have mentioned, event delegation using `on()` (if using a newer jQuery) or `delegate()` (if using an older) is the *best*, as it only attaches one event listener and will work with future elements added after the event is attached.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.record', function() {
   // Any `a` element with a class of `record` was clicked, now or in the future.
});
```

I've used `document` here, but you should use the nearest ancestor which won't change, which may be the `ul` element you have described.